# WearableListView LongClick

Tags: android, wear-os

I have been trying to add a longClickListener to WearableListView

This is what I have currently done:

```
listView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here listView is a WearableListView. When I long click the function does not get called. 
I understand that for single click we have to set `listView.setClickListener()` and not `listView.setOnClickListener()` is there a similar approach to long clicks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use onItemLongClick instead of LongClick

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi! Sadly there doesn't seem to be `setOnItemLongClickListener()` in WearableListView. Checked the reference too [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WearableListView.html)

Comment: ok..in refrence there is no LongClick too for Wearable List View

Comment: you can apply LongClick on list item's main layout

Comment: The list is in a Fragment so tried putting the onLongClick on that but that does not work  either. Also I need to retrieve the item that the user long clicked on which won't work by this method.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this. My hacky solution was to extend wearableListView and override its onTouch method to see if there's a long touch been done. Also makes sure the touch takes place on the center item. I had to add a centered boolean to the item view.

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(!this.isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                moved = false;
                timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                initialTouch = event.getRawX();
                //handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1000);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                if (!moved && timestamp + 1000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {

                    Rect rect;
                    for(int i = 0;i<getChildCount();i++){View v = getChildAt(i);
                        if(v instanceof WearableListItemSensor){
                            if(((WearableListItemSensor) v).isCenter) {
                                rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
                                if(rect.contains( (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())){
                                    //long pressed center
                                    if (mLongClickListener != null)
                                        mLongClickListener.onLongClick((int)v.getTag());
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                if(Math.abs(event.getRawX() - initialTouch) >= 2)
                    moved=true;
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```